# Fix java.lang.module.ResolutionException: two modules export the same package to another module in a non-modular app

Tags: java, maven, javafx, java-module

I'm trying to build a non-modular application (no module-info.java files) with JavaFX 11 using Maven.

[As suggested on openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven), I'm using [JavaFX Maven plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin) for that.

But in respond to `mvn javafx:run` I get the following error:

```
 [INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.2:run (default-cli) @ server ---  
 Error occurred during initialization of boot layer  
 java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules lucene.core and
 lucene.misc export package org.apache.lucene.store to module javassist  
 [ERROR] Command execution failed.
```

I'm using Hibernate Search 5.11.2 which depends on `org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.5` and `org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:5.5.5`.

As far as I understand from the [API](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_5/core/index.html), these jars are simple pre-JDK9 jars. So they should be parts of the unnamed module and I should get no errors.
Or am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like a bug in the JavaFX Maven plugin, as it is adding _all_ dependencies to the `module-path`, because all artifacts are resolved as modules from their package name.

Comment: @JoséPereda is there a way to disable this behavior and leave artifacts in the `class-path`?

Comment: Not directly, but there is a possible fix in the plugin, that will be available soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in [this PR](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin/pull/35).

So either build and install the snapshot or wait until version 0.0.3 will be released, if you are facing the similar issue.

Comment: JavaFX Maven plugin `0.0.3` has been released.

Answer (score 0):

Faced this in javafx-maven-plugin **0.0.5** with IntelliJ
Kept getting different errors like :

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules plexus.archiver and plexus.io export package org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources to module j2objc.annotations
```

Had to clear all libraries (except org.javafx) from the Module Settings and rebuild the project, which finally fixed the issue.